# How to run shell script from a shell script without terminating it

Tags: bash, shell, zsh

I am working on a shell script which will install Debian packages for me, copy config files etc.

The problem is that when i try to execute external script, the parent script gets terminated, i have a script like this:

```
# changing shell

chsh -s $(which zsh)

# installing oh-my-zsh

sh -c "$(wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/robbyrussell/oh-my- 
zsh/master/tools/install.sh -O -)"

# copying zsh config file

rsync -a .zshrc ~/
```

My script terminates after running second step.

Thank you

Comment: How do you know it is terminated after the second step? can you provide any output / indicators?

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like this

```
sh -c "sleep 3" &
echo "We are waiting"
wait
```

Here you can check what the `wait` does https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Job-Control-Builtins.html